# Background Image Only Showing White Background CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a veteran to CSS and HTML, but never before have I seen this problem. I have the background image, CSS, and HTML files placed properly. I believe I have all the code right too since I checked it against a site I already made, but my image will not appear for anything.

CSS

```
body {
background-image: url(am-stage.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: black;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> AM </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Chrome is giving an error saying that the CSS file can't be found. Not sure why though. The CSS is in the same directory as the HTML and the image.

Comment: Is that all of your page? With no content, the body will be empty, and therefore have a height of 0. Solution: add `html, body {height:100%}`

Comment: Try maybe adding comas to the url like: background-image: url("am-stage.png");

Comment: Mr Lister, Kalia, tried both and still a white background.

Comment: @Jeff maybe you have the wrong image url.

Comment: I wish, but no it's correct.

Comment: @kalia Do you mean quotes, not com(m)as?

Comment: I knew what they meant, no harm

Comment: @j08691 yes, sorry, English is not my native language.

Comment: @j08691 Quotes are called inverted commas in some parts of the world.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, Sublime wasn't saving the CSS as a CSS file. I told it to save as a CSS, but it wasn't adding the extension this time for some reason. I just chose CSS and manually put in the .css at the end and now it's working.